# Scrapy extracting content from HTML no output

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

So basically I want to pull the parts under the tr-mfgPartNumber class from this html but have problems.

- first I thought it was my syntax for calling each class but still no output
- Tried adding another for loop to go to the whole body class
  if anyone can check if my code has an error in the the way im calling the classes that would be great!

  ```
  import scrapy

  class DigiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
      name = 'digi'
      allowed_domains = ['digikey.com']
      start_urls = ['https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-1%7C428%2C-8%7C774%2C7%7C1/']

      def parse(self, response):
          data={}
          parts=response.css('tbody.InkPart')
          for part in parts:
              for p in part.css('td.tr-mfgPartNumber'):
                  data['href'] = p.css('a::attr(href)').extract()
                  yield data
  ```

**Below is the HTML**

```html
<tbody id="lnkPart" cookie-tracking="ref_page_event=Select Part;available_parameters=[&quot;s&quot;,&quot;pv1989&quot;,&quot;pv142&quot;,&quot;pv2042&quot;,&quot;pv2192&quot;,&quot;pv276&quot;,&quot;pv252&quot;,&quot;pv16&quot;,&quot;pv1291&quot;];">

<tr>
    
    <td class="tr-compareParts" align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="part" value="428-3574-2-ND" id="428-3574-2-ND" onclick="partClick();">
        <label title="Compare Parts" for="428-3574-2-ND"></label>
    </td>
    
    <td class="tr-datasheet">
            <a class="lnkDatasheet" href="https://www.cypress.com/file/43021/download" target="_blank" track-data="ref_page_event=Display Asset;page_title=Datasheet;asset_type=Datasheet">
                <img class="datasheet-img" src="//www.digikey.com/Web%20Export/Common/icons/datasheet.png" alt="CY62157EV30LL-45ZSXIT Datasheet" title="CY62157EV30LL-45ZSXIT Datasheet">
            </a>
    </td>
    
    <td class="tr-image">
        <a href="/product-detail/en/cypress-semiconductor-corp/CY62157EV30LL-45ZSXIT/428-3574-2-ND/1205268">
            <img class="pszoomer" zoomimg="//media.digikey.com/Renders/Cypress%20Semi%20Renders/428;51-85087;Z,ZS;44.jpg" border="0" height="64" src="//media.digikey.com/Renders/Cypress%20Semi%20Renders/428;51-85087;Z,ZS;44_tmb.jpg" alt="CY62157EV30LL-45ZSXIT - Cypress Semiconductor Corp" title="CY62157EV30LL-45ZSXIT - Cypress Semiconductor Corp">
        </a>
    </td>
    
    <td class="tr-dkPartNumber nowrap-culture">                             
        <a href="/product-detail/en/cypress-semiconductor-corp/CY62157EV30LL-45ZSXIT/428-3574-2-ND/1205268">
            428-3574-2-ND
        </a>
            <div class="product-indicator-collection">
<a class="align-indicator-collection" href="javascript:msgBox('#dlgRohs');">
<img class="rohs-foilage" src="//www.digikey.com/web%20export/common/mkt/en/leaf.png" border="0" alt="This part is RoHS compliant." title="This part is RoHS compliant.">
</a>


</div>
       
    </td>
    
    <td class="tr-mfgPartNumber">
        <a href="/product-detail/en/cypress-semiconductor-corp/CY62157EV30LL-45ZSXIT/428-3574-2-ND/1205268">
            <span>CY62157EV30LL-45ZSXIT</span>
        </a>
    </td>
```

Comment: did you try to display full HTML and see if this element exists when you scrapy try to get it? Maybe server doesn't like you and bots and it sends HTML with warning for bots or with captcha.

Comment: there is `<tbody id="InkPart">`, with `ID` not `CLASS` so you need `tbody#InkPart` with `#`, not `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried the same code, scrapy was getting empty response. Maybe the site was detecting and blocking the spider. After using user agent, it worked.

Here's the code below (I also changed "tbody.InkPart" to "tbody#lnkPart", it was a syntax mistake in your code, though it is not needed since there's only one tbody tag):

```
import scrapy


class DigiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'digi'
    allowed_domains = ['digikey.com']
    custom_settings = {
        "USER_AGENT": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
    }
    start_urls = ['https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-1%7C428%2C-8%7C774%2C7%7C1/']

    def parse(self, response):
        data={}
        parts=response.css('tbody#lnkPart')
        for part in parts:
            for p in part.css('td.tr-mfgPartNumber'):
                data['href'] = p.css('a::attr(href)').extract()
                yield data
```